# Getting ActionBar color or background in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So far I am able to change the ActionBar background color but what I need is to get the current background color from the ActionBar. How could I do this?

This is my code:

```
int newColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    Drawable colorDrawable  = new ColorDrawable(newColor);
    Drawable bottomDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bottom);
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { colorDrawable, bottomDrawable });
    ((Activity) context).getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
}
```

Comment: can you find something ?